# Writing regex with certain pattern sed/awk/perl

Tags: perl, sed, awk

How can I capture group 1 of the pattern below with any of the following(sed, awk, perl) ?

Regex pattern is `\[(.*)\]` for the below line, I want to capture group 1, meaning anything between `[]`

```
Processing record with rowkey [fdebae87f9b7bcb7f698a0723cd1474b3a84bbb1] with these rules
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve, above row is the simple input. Below is simple output:

```
fdebae87f9b7bcb7f698a0723cd1474b3a84bbb1
```

*Question Update :*

**Actual sample input is**(sorry for ommiting didn't know it was necessary and bit more complex) :

```
Processing record with rowkey [fdebae87f9b7bcb7f698a0723cd1474b3a84bbb1] with these rules [[COUNT_ALL]].
```

Comment: You have captured it by using the round brackets. It will be in $1 in perl, for instance. You need to make your question clearer: What are you trying to do with it next?

Comment: @Alex hi Alex I updated my question, it seems a bit more clear now

Answer (score 5):

You're experiencing **greediness** issues.

Hence you're matching:

```
fdebae87f9b7bcb7f698a0723cd1474b3a84bbb1] with these rules [[COUNT_ALL]
```

instead of:

```
fdebae87f9b7bcb7f698a0723cd1474b3a84bbb1
```

Remember: `.*` matching is *greedy*. (matches the longest possibile span)

Possible solutions:

- reducing greediness: (not on sed and awk IIRC)
  `\[(.*?)\]`
- reducing greediness the old way:
  `\[([^\]]*)\]`
- just matching word characters: (`[A-Za-z_]`)
  `\[(\w*)\]`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo 'Processing record with rowkey [fdebae87f9b7bcb7f698a0723cd1474b3a84bbb1] with these rules' | command_bellowing
```

#### sed

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)\].*/\1/'
```

#### gawk

```
$ gawk '{print gensub(/.*\[(.*)\].*/, "\\1", "g")}'
```

#### perl

```
$ perl -ne 's/.*\[(.*)\].*/\1/;print'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, you have captured it. If you want to get the result, try:

`s/\[(.*)\]/$1/`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^[^[]*\[\([^]]*\).*/\1/' file
```